# Join Counts of Different Attributes

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have 3 tables:

T1(A, B, CountX)

T2(A, B, CountY)

T3(A, B, CountZ)

And I want to create the following table:

T123(A, B, CountX, CountY, CountZ)

where T1, T2, and T3 are joined by the tuple A, B being the same for all 3 tables. How would I accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I didn't specify this earlier, but instead of inner join, what about outer join? There could be counts of 0 for X, Y, and Z instead of deleting them from the table. For example, I wish an entry such as this:

a, b, 2, 0, 1

to exist in the table, but T2 may not contain an entry with a, b, 0. Some tuple of a, b might not exist in T1, but it might exist in T2. In T1, T2, and T3, there are no tables with counts = 0

Comment: get the individual counts then join.  otherwise cardinality may artificially inflate counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `union all` and aggregation:

```
select a, b, max(countx) as countx, max(county) as county, max(countz) as countz
from ((select a, b, countx, null as county, null as countz
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select a, b, null as countx, county, null as countz
       from t2
      ) union all
      (select a, b, null as countx, null as county, countz
       from t3
      )
     ) t123
group by a, b;
```

Comment: Wow! This seems to do it. Now I'll just take some time to digest why this query works.

Answer (score 0):

You want simple joins:

```
select t1.*, t2.CountY, t3.CountZ
from t1
inner join t2 on t2.A = t1.A and t2.B = t1.B
inner join t3 on t3.A = t1.A and t3.B = t1.B
```

You can turn this into a `create table` statement as follows:

```
create table t123 as
select t1.*, t2.CountY, t3.CountZ
from t1
inner join t2 on t2.A = t1.A and t2.B = t1.B
inner join t3 on t3.A = t1.A and t3.B = t1.B
```

Beware that creating tables like this does not allow defining pripary keys, foreign keys constraints, indexes or other such table attributes. It is generally a better practice to create the table first, and then populate it, using the `insert ... select ...` syntax.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't specific in my question, but I was thinking of a full outer join, where there can be 0s as counts for X, Y, and Z. Some tuple of a, b might not exist in T1, but it might exist in T2. In T1, T2, and T3, there are no tables with counts = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the values from the tables where (inner join on) A and B is the same:

```
SELECT T1.A as A, T1.B as B, CountX, CountY, CountZ
FROM T1,T2,T3
WHERE T1.A=T2.A AND T2.A=T3.A
    AND T1.B=T2.B AND T2.B=T3.B
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
Select a.A, a.B, T1.CountX, T2.CountY, T3.CountZ int T123
from 
(Select distinct A, B from T1 union Select distinct A, B from T2 union Select distinct A, B from T3) a  
inner join T1 on a.A = T1.A and a.B = T1.B
inner join T2 on a.A = T2.A and a.B = T2.B
inner join T3 on a.A = T3.A and a.B = T3.B
```

Let me know

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific enough in my original question. You can take a look at my edit. There are problems when count could be null or 0.